# How to get code coverage using (Maven-Java-Selenium) test of nodejs code

Tags: node.js, maven, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, istanbul

-> I have installed istanbul using npm install istanbul
-> I am able to do instrumentation of my code using command
          istanbul instrument (source code of product i.e path of all js scripts) -o (path of my test suite)

->It copies all the src js file in my test folder.

Now i did n't find any command which i can use to get coverage after running my pom.xml using command- mvn test -f //path/to/pom.xml

Also i tried this using nightwatch framework but it is giving coverage of my script only, rather then giving coverage of source js files. command used was istanbul cover test.js

Looking forward for your help